# Make Content Show Up As User Scrolls with Javascript/HTML/CSS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want contents to be hidden, and when the user is at appropriate position of the page, I want it to show up. I am thinking of something like [Apple - iPhone 6](https://www.apple.com/iphone-6/) page. I googled for a while but I couldn't seem to find anything appropriate. How would I do this? Is it even possible for amateur people like me to recreate? Sorry for having no code, but everything I tried hasn't been working.

Comment: Something like on this page? http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Exactly like that page. That's what I want it to look like.

Comment: It is definitely possible.  You would need to use jQuery.  Is that okay with you?

Comment: Yes, I can use jQuery.

Comment: Are you open to using jQuery plugins?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved through the use of jQuery. There is a method, $(window).scroll(), which is called when the user scrolls the window. An example use is below

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(this).scrollTop() > 600 {
        // do something (called after the user has scrolled more than 600 pixels down)
    }
});
```